# Any tweaks after installing lubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, lxde, tweak

I have recently installed lubuntu and want some software to make it run smoothly.Also, after i installed lubuntu, i saw no grub image (it seems bad without image) So, Please tell me how to set  grub image

Answer (score 4):

1. First update your system , so that It will let you install updates.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
2. To play MP3 songs you might need some codecs , so

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras
   ```
3. Open Ubuntu Software Center and Look for VLC Media Player.
4. For Having better Battery you can use tlp.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install tlp
   ```
5. To change GRUB background , you can use Grub Customizer

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
   ```

Comment: The OP is using Lubuntu, so instead of installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, you should install `lubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 0):

To complete rajagenupula answer, you can find a complete post about it on forumubuntu.
Here is the link : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1880394